# JavaScript - Get class name

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, openlayers-3

I have a problem with this OpenLayers 3 classes whichs extends ol.geom.Geometry. I want to know the constructor name of ol.geom.Point for example, so i do :

```
ol.geom.Point.name
```

But i get nothing, even if I create an instance and try to get the constructor name :

```
var p = new ol.geom.Point([0,0]); p.constructor.name;
```

The implementation of ol.geom.Point can be found [here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/geom/point.js).

```
ol.geom.Point = function(coordinates, opt_layout) {...}
```

And I have done a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrrz7w6z/1/) to reproduce this behaviour.

Reading docs from MDN :

> Browsers that implement ES6 functions can infer the name of an
>   anonymous function from its syntactic position. For example:
>
> var f = function() {}; console.log(f.name); // "f"

**So, what i'm doing wrong or what i'm missing ?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what browser are you testing this with. For all I know f.name is only supported by Firefox .

Comment: I'm testing in Firefox.

Comment: Just curious why you need a constructor name. If you want to set custom properties use `ol.geom.Point#setProperties`.

Comment: Hi @JonatasWalker, i'm implementing a class extending ol.source.Vector in order to only accept one Geometry type. Let's say something like : var myPointSource = new OneGeometrySource({ geometry : ol.geom.Point }); I'm overriding addFeature function to get it work. But now I want to throw an error if you try to add another else Geometry disctint to ol.geom.Point saying something like "This instance only accepts ol.geom.Point geometries". So that is what I need the class name.

Comment: I know I can just test if is instanceof ol.geom.XXXX and return the string manually. But I would like a better solution if possible.

Comment: I see but I'm afraid you'll have to go with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2):

To access the `name` property like this in your scenario would mean using the 'Inferred names on anonymous functions'. At the time of writing, this is only supported by the not-yet publicly stable release of **Chrome 51**.

This is stated in the MDN docs that you have probably been reading through. Refer to the bottom browser compatibility table and consult the 'Inferred names on anonymous functions' support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: Thank you so much for your anwser but I have tested in chrome 51 and no result.

Answer (score -1):

That's a, ***JavaScript - Blind Spot***.

---

Requesting a thing such as:

```
var f = function() {}; 
    console.log(f.name); // to return:
>> f
```

is nothing wrong. Moreover, from a human perspective, seems such a natural thing to ask for - but from a machine point of view, it's so counterintuitive that, to make a simple thing like this work - you'll probably have to break lots of things you probably love. For it might require quite an ugly patch.

Doing that, *would & should* make it possible to ask any pointer, (variable, regardless if it's pointing to a primitive or a full fledged object) -What's its variable name? 
But than you get in trouble: -Should it return its pointer name at its current state handle or only its original initial assignment? And if so, why not the other?

I'd love it. But I suspect, it just isn't going to be so for quite some time...